# Scroll to anchor if URL contains a certain word

Tags: javascript

**Apologies if this has already been asked, but I couldn't find a specific solution.**

I am using a set `uneditable plugin` on my `website` which uses pages. I cannot edit the `code` for the `plugin`. The paged content is towards the bottom of the page that it is displayed on: [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FinN1.jpg)

When the user clicks on the pages, it adds **"page/2/"** **etc to the end of the current URL**, but it shows the user the top of the page.

I have added an anchor just before the plugin, but how can I scroll the user to the anchor based on if the **URL** contains **"page/2/" or "page/3/" etc.?**

> Simply: If the URL contains the word "page", then scroll to #anchor

Thanks!

Comment: Can you be more specific about the plugin your using? This questions sounds like one that you might want to redirect to the plugin authors.

Comment: You can get the pathname with `window.location.pathname`. Get the anchor element position using properties like`offsetTop` and `offsetHeight`. Then, you can scroll with `window.scrollTo` method.

Comment: @Hangindev or even easier... [`Element.scrollIntoView()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)

Comment: @Phil Yup, even better and straightforward.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it working, thanks @hangindev

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if(window.location.href.indexOf("page") > -1) {
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
         $('html, body').animate({
           'scrollTop':   $('#anchor').offset().top
         }, 1000);
    });
})(jQuery);
}
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps

```html
<a href="#bottom">Bottom</a>
<h1 id="bottom">This is the bottom! </h1>
```

Comment: Thanks, but what I'm trying to do, is use javascript to essentially see if the URL contains the word "page" and if it does, to scroll down to an anchor. Apologies, will edit the OP.